# I need to understand the process for immigrating to the Netherlands

Tags: working-visas, netherlands, marriage, non-residents

I am from the Caribbean and my fiancé is Dutch. We plan to be married and stay in the Netherlands. What is the process for me being from the Caribbean? Can I obtain a work visa for the length of time nessesary to apply for residency? What is the step by step process for us?

Comment: The process is all laid out for you at https://ind.nl/en/family/Pages/Spouse-or-partner.aspx. You generally won't be able to work until after your residence application is approved. The specifics of the process probably depend on whether you can enter the country without a visa for short stays, and "the Caribbean" is not a precise enough description ofvyour citizenship to know. The answer will be different if you are from, say, Jamaica or Trinidad or indeed Aruba.

Comment: Am from the Bahamas

Comment: The civic integration exam. Can it be done online?. The consulate in the bahamas does not have any knowledge of it

Comment: That is truly bizarre. Any Dutch person with even the slightest interest in immigration knows about the integration exam -- and that is quite a few Dutch people, because the subject of immigration is quite controversial. The idea that an employee or officer of the foreign service doesn't know about it is surprising indeed. Was the person you spoke to from Europe or the Caribbean?

Comment: From the Bahamas, i spoke with him and now he referring me to the dutch embassy in miami